# How can I minify css files in different folders so I don't get pathing issues?

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman

This is my GruntJS cssmin script.

```
cssmin: {
  add_banner: {
    options: {
      banner: '/* Minified on <%= grunt.template.today("yyyy-mm-dd hh:MM:ss")%> by GruntJS-cssmin */'
    },
    files: {
      'public/home_assets/css/compressed.min.css': [
        'public/home_assets/css/**/*.css',
        'public/home_assets/vendor/**/*.css'
        ]
    }
  }
},
```

It works correctly and minify CSS files. However, CSS files under `css/vendor/vendorname` folder minifies into `css` folder so their pathing gets messed.

For example, `./image.jpg` should be `./vendor/vendorname/image.jpg` otherwise their relativity gets broken.

How can I solve this issue? What kind of tricks can I use?

Answer (score 1):

You can configure `grunt-contrib-cssmin` to process multiple target directories with corresponding destinations by modifying your `grunt.initConfig` lines for `cssmin` to something like this:

```
files: {
  './css/compressed.min.css': ['./css/**/*.css'],
  './vendor/compressedvendor.min.css':['./vendor/**/*.css']
}
```

**Edit:**
*Based upon your comments below, you wanted a single file and not two.*

The [sample Gruntfile.js](http://gruntjs.com/sample-gruntfile) shows how you would use `grunt-contrib-concat` to first join the files together then you can run `cssmin` (instead of `uglify` in the sample).

Your Gruntfile.js might therefore look like this as a result:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {

    grunt.initConfig({
        concat: {
            dist: {
                src: ['./css/**/*.css', './vendor/**/*.css'],
                dest: './dist/tmp/concat.css'
            }
        },
        cssmin: {
            dist: {
                files: {
                    './dist/compressed.min.css': [ './dist/tmp/concat.css' ]
                }
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-cssmin');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');

    grunt.registerTask('default', ['concat', 'cssmin']);
}
```

As you can see in the code above, you might want to consider whether you should have a source and destination file structure to make it easier to manage the files.  You'll probably also want to review other `grunt-contrib` plugins like `-clean` to help automate even more build tasks...

Comment: Thought about it but then there will be 2 requests to my web server.

Comment: Does the answer I gave solve the question you asked?  Just curious if I misread your original question or if you are just thinking out loud here about your options...

Comment: If I'm going to have a minified css in every folder, then it violates the whole point of compressing and minifying. Output must be 1 css file at maximum so your answer doesn't solve my issue.